# Permanently disable internal disk on Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, unmount

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on an old MacBook. This MacBook has both an internal SSD and an internal HDD. Ubuntu is running from the SSD and the HDD is not required in Ubuntu.

However, it is automatically mounted and is spinning all the time.

When I use

```
sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sda
```

the HDD stops spinning for a short time, but restarts after a very little while.

I also tried disabling udisks2 temporarily, but this did not change the behavihour.

Any ideas are very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from `/etc/fstab` and it will not automatically mount. It will still be available and shown in your filemanager for you to mount.